# Error in Zygmund Measure and Integral Lemma 4.19

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> If $f$ is a simple function taking (distinct) values $a_1,\dots,a_n$ on (disjoint) sets $E_1,\dots,E_N$, then
> $$f(x)=\sum^N_{k=1}a_k\chi_{E_k}(x)\text{,}$$
> where $\chi_{E_k}$ is the indicator function of $E_k$. $f$ is measurable if and only if $E_1,\dots,E_N$ are (Lebesgue) measurable.

> A function defined on a measurable set $E$ has property $\mathscr{C}$ on $E$ if given $\epsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F\subset E$ such that
> (i) $|E-F|<\epsilon$,
> (ii) $f$ is continuous relative to $F$.

> **(4.19) Lemma** A simple measurable function has property $\mathscr{C}$
> *Proof.* Suppose that $f$ is a simple measurable function on $E$, taking distinct values $a_1,\dots,a_N$ on measurable subsets $E_1,\dots,E_N$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose closed sets $F_j\subset E_j$ with $|E_j-F_j|<\epsilon/N$. Then the set $F=\bigcup^N_{j=1}F_j$ is closed, and since $E-F=\bigcup E_j-\bigcup F_j\subset \bigcup(E_j-F_j)$, we have $|E-F|\leq\sum|E_j-F_j|<\epsilon$. It remains only to show that $f$ is continuous on $F$. Note that each $F_j$ is relatively open in $F$, so the only points of $F$ in a small neighborhood of any point of $F_j$ are points of $F_j$ itself. The continuity on $F$ of $f$ follows from this since $f$ is constant on each $F_j$.

Let $a_1=1$, $E_1=\mathbb{Z}$, $a_2=2$, $E_2=\{n+1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $f=a_1E_1+a_2E_2$ is a simple measurable function, and $F_j=E_j$ is a closed set with $|E_j-F_j|=0$. But $F_1$ is not open in $F_1\cup F_2$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example $F_1$ is open in $F_1\cup F_2$. To see this consider the complement of $F_1$ in $F_1\cup F_2$. This set has no limit points, so it is closed.

Alternatively, you can argue  that the complement of $F_2$ in the real line is open and its intersection with $F_1\cup F_2$ is exactly $F_1$.